# zsh scripting - How do I NOT match a pattern in filename generation?

Tags: zsh, wildcards

I'm currently trying to loop through a set of directories, but only the ones I care about.

```
$ ls -d */
cfdpost_statefiles/     p050L0260/  p050L0510/  p060L0390/  p070L0260/  p070L0510/  p092L0390/  p097L0260/  p110L0390/  p131L0325/  p150L0510/  profiles/
ERCOFTAC_TestSettings/  p050L0390/  p060L0260/  p060L0510/  p070L0390/  p084L0510/  p094L0325/  p100L0510/  p125L0510/  p136L0260/  p162L0260/  settings/
```

I want to match all the `p###*` directories except for the ones beginning with `p125` and `p150`.

If I just do patterns with a pipe, I get:

```
$ for dir in ./p(125|150)*(/); echo $dir
./p125L0510
./p150L0510
```

However, if I try and use the `^` like it shows [in it's documentation](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Filename-Generation):

```
$ for dir in ./p^(125|150)*(/); echo $dir
zsh: no matches found: ./p^(125|150)*(/)
```

Any ideas how to proceed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `EXTENDED_GLOB` options needs to be set for zsh.

To see if it's been set, run `setopt` to display the options that have been set:

```
$ setopt | grep glob
extendedglob
```

If it isn't set, run `setopt extended_glob`.

NOTE: this will cause the `~`, `^`, and `#` to not be expanded on.

---

The issue in my case was that, although I set this option in the shell, *I was running the for loop in a script.* The script starts its own shell to run in and thus didn't have the option set.

To fix this particular issue, put `setopt extendedglob` in the script itself.