# zsh negate glob number range

Tags: zsh, wildcards

I have a list of files:

```bsh
➜ ls
1_test.txt  3_test.txt  5_test.txt  7_test.txt  9_test.txt   otherfiles_1  otherfiles_3
2_test.txt  4_test.txt  6_test.txt  8_test.txt  10_test.txt  otherfiles_2
```

I want to select all the files *except* `{1-5}_test.txt`.

I can successfully glob `{1-5}_test.txt` via: `<1-5>_test.txt` or even just `<1-5>[^0-9]*`.

But `^<1-5>_test.txt` doesn't work:

```
➜ ls ^<1-5>_test.txt
zsh: no matches found: ^<1-5>_test.txt
```

Any ideas what to change?

#### Edit:

See duplicate/similar question here: [zsh scripting - How do I NOT match a pattern in filename generation?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/516963/zsh-scripting-how-do-i-not-match-a-pattern-in-filename-generation)

Solution is to `setopt extendedglob`.

Comment: `(^<1-5>)_test.txt` appears to work for me - provided EXTENDED_GLOB is enabled (`setopt extended_glob`) - not sure if that's the right way though

Comment: or `*~<1-5>_test.txt` ...

Comment: What do you mean by doesn't work? `^<1-5>_test.txt` matches all the files that `<1-5>_test.txt` doesn't match, isn't this what you want? One thing that isn't clear: do you want to include or exclude `2_test.txt`, `3_test.txt` and `4_test.txt`? You mention a range in the question title, but then you say you want to exclude `{1,5}_test.txt` and that's just `1_test.txt` and `5_test.txt`, not a range.

Comment: @Gilles'SO-stopbeingevil' Thanks for catching the issues in my question. I've updated the question. Setting `setopt extendedglob` removed the error.

Comment: @steeldriver That won't print the `otherfiles_*` (quoting the OP: "all the files except `{1-5}_test.txt`").

Comment: @mosvy It actually is working as I specified. `ls ^(<1-5>)_test.txt ===> 10_test.txt  6_test.txt  7_test.txt  8_test.txt  9_test.txt  otherfiles_1  otherfiles_2  otherfiles_3`

Comment: @JamesWright I was talking about steeldriver's pattern from the [1st comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/574935/zsh-negate-glob-number-range#comment1070413_574935): `ls (^<1-5>)_test.txt`

Comment: @Gilles'SO-stopbeingevil' - the funny part is that OP here is the author of both the Q and the A over there...

Comment: @don_crissti hahaha. See, I knew I had run into this kind of problem before and solved it on SE, but couldn't look it up to save my life. :/